# Set default connection ethernet Java in Andorid?

Tags: java, android, flutter, connection, network-connection

My tablet has 2 network connections(UsbEtherhet and wifi) but I want to default connection Usb/Ethernet.

Android 10 and previous versions default connection is Usb/Ethernet but Android 11 default connection is wifi .How can set default can you help?

I'm using flutter and kotlin for native (java is possible)

Comment: Did you find an answer to this ?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find